# Custom SOAP Web Service variable maxLength

Tags: webservices, soap

is there a way to set maxLength value for String variables exposed through my custom soap web service?

```
global class MySoapService {
  webService String myName;
  ...
}
```

Let's say I would need to limit myName variable to accept only max 10 charactes. How would I manage to do this?

Comment: There is a soap header named AllowFieldTruncationHeader, which defines behavior for too long String fields (link to documentation: https://www.salesforce.com/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_header_allowfieldtruncation.htm). But that header is controlled by web service client, so it isn't very helpful.  Usually I create request validation class, which contains my validation logic, when request is invalid I throw an exception with message on what's wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on some now deleted answers and comments, the question is how to communicate to consumers of the WSDL what the maximum allowed length of a string parameter is.

In [XML Schema](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_schema) used within WSDL, the idea of [restrictions](http://www.w3schools.com/schema/schema_facets.asp) is used to limit acceptable values of existing types. Here is an example for for the length of a string [Is it possible to require min and max string length for param in wsdl file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8152832/is-it-possible-to-require-min-and-max-string-length-for-param-in-wsdl-file).

(Enforcement of these restrictions is not implemented in all frameworks - for example [Axis 1.x did not enforce them](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AXIS-119).)

There is no annotation in Apex to add the maxLength value to your class, so in theory you would have to take the WSDL generated from your class, manually modify it, then generate Apex from it using "Generate from WSDL" (AKA [wsdl2apex](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wsdl2apex)). But the generator does not support this pattern - see [Empty sub-classes in output of wsdl2apex??](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/ForumsMain?id=906F00000008un4IAA) - so that won't work.

In short, your approach does not look possible in Salesforce.